# Dumping Observable<byte[]> to a stream

Tags: c#, .net, stream, system.reactive

I currently have an `Observable<byte[]>` that is, in fact, a sequence of chunks of a source file, using [this](https://github.com/RxDave/Rxx/blob/master/Main/Source/Rxx.Bindings-Net451/System/IO/StreamExtensions.cs#L56) method.

It "chunkifies" the stream as a sequence of `byte[]`.

The problem is that, given this sequence, I would like to write it to a destination stream. In other words, I have to dump each `byte[]` to a file stream until the sequence is finished, but also, I should await until the sequence finishes.

So far, this code I created works, but I'm afraid it's not the correct way to do it way to do it. The relevant part in which the `IObservable<byte[]>` is handled is the `Download` method.

```
async Task Main()
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()) 
    {
        var downloader = new HttpDownloader(httpClient);
        var destinationPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "test.zip");
        await downloader.Download("https://github.com/gus33000/MSM8994-8992-NT-ARM64-Drivers/archive/master.zip", destinationPath);
        Console.WriteLine("File downloaded to " + destinationPath);
    }   
}

public class HttpDownloader
{
    private readonly HttpClient client;

    public HttpDownloader(HttpClient client)
    {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public async Task Download(string url, string path, IDownloadProgress progressObserver = null, int timeout = 30)
    {
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(path))
        {
            await Download(url, fileStream, progressObserver, timeout);
        }
    }

    private async Task Download(string url, Stream destination, IDownloadProgress progressObserver = null,
        int timeout = 30)
    {
        long? totalBytes = 0;
        long bytesWritten = 0;

        await ObservableMixin.Using(() => client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead),
                s =>
                {
                    totalBytes = s.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
                    if (!totalBytes.HasValue)
                    {
                        progressObserver?.Percentage.OnNext(double.PositiveInfinity);
                    }
                    return ObservableMixin.Using(() => s.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(),
                        contentStream => contentStream.ReadToEndObservable());
                })
            .Do(bytes =>
            {
                bytesWritten += bytes.Length;
                if (totalBytes.HasValue)
                {
                    progressObserver?.Percentage.OnNext((double)bytesWritten / totalBytes.Value);
                }

                progressObserver?.BytesDownloaded?.OnNext(bytesWritten);
            })
            .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout))
            .Select(bytes => Observable.FromAsync(async () =>
            {
                await destination.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                return Unit.Default;
            }))
            .Merge(1);
    }

    private static readonly int BufferSize = 8192;

    public async Task<Stream> GetStream(string url, IDownloadProgress progress = null, int timeout = 30)
    {
        var tmpFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetTempFileName());
        var stream = File.Create(tmpFile, BufferSize, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);

        await Download(url, stream, progress, timeout);
        return stream;
    }
}

public interface IDownloadProgress
{
    ISubject<double> Percentage { get; set; }
    ISubject<long> BytesDownloaded { get; set; }
}

public static class ObservableMixin
{
    public static IObservable<TSource> Using<TSource, TResource>(
        Func<Task<TResource>> resourceFactoryAsync,
        Func<TResource, IObservable<TSource>> observableFactory)
        where TResource : IDisposable =>
        Observable.FromAsync(resourceFactoryAsync).SelectMany(
            resource => Observable.Using(() => resource, observableFactory));
}

public static class StreamExtensions
{
    internal const int defaultBufferSize = 4096;

    public static IObservable<byte[]> ReadToEndObservable(this Stream stream)
    {
        return stream.ReadToEndObservable(new byte[defaultBufferSize]);
    }

    public static IObservable<byte[]> ReadToEndObservable(this Stream stream, int bufferSize)
    {
        return stream.ReadToEndObservable(new byte[bufferSize]);
    }

    internal static IObservable<byte[]> ReadToEndObservable(this Stream stream, byte[] buffer)
    {
        return Observable.Create<byte[]>(
            observer =>
            {
                var subscription = new SerialDisposable();

                return new CompositeDisposable(
                    subscription,
                    Scheduler.Immediate.Schedule(
                        self =>
                        {
                            bool continueReading = true;

                            subscription.SetDisposableIndirectly(() =>
                                stream.ReadObservable(buffer).SubscribeSafe(
                                    data =>
                                    {
                                        if (data.Length > 0)
                                        {
                                            observer.OnNext(data);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            continueReading = false;
                                        }
                                    },
                                    observer.OnError,
                                    () =>
                                    {
                                        if (continueReading)
                                        {
                                            self();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            observer.OnCompleted();
                                        }
                                    }));
                        }));
            });
    }

    internal static IObservable<byte[]> ReadObservable(this Stream stream, byte[] buffer)
    {
        return stream.ReadObservable(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).Select(
            read =>
            {
                byte[] data;

                if (read <= 0)
                {
                    data = new byte[0];
                }
                else if (read == buffer.Length)
                {
                    data = (byte[])buffer.Clone();
                }
                else
                {
                    data = new byte[read];

                    Array.Copy(buffer, data, read);
                }

                return data;
            });
    }

    public static IObservable<int> ReadObservable(this Stream stream, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        return Observable.StartAsync(cancel => stream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count, cancel));
    }   
}

public static class SerialDisposableExtensions
{
    public static void SetDisposableIndirectly(this SerialDisposable disposable, Func<IDisposable> factory)
    {
        var indirection = new SingleAssignmentDisposable();

        disposable.Disposable = indirection;

        indirection.Disposable = factory();
    }
}


public static class SafeObservableExtensions
{
    public static IDisposable SubscribeSafe<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Action<T> onNext,
        Action<Exception> onError, Action onCompleted)
    {
        return source.SubscribeSafe(Observer.Create<T>(onNext, onError, onCompleted));
    }
}
```

Does it look OK?

Comment: You can't do both `obs.Subscribe(bytes => stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length));` & `await obs;` as they cause two separate subscriptions to your `obs` and you now potentially have a race condition. You need to ensure there is only one.

Comment: Hello @Enigmativity! Thanks for reviewing the code. Can you please, take a look to the edited question? Is it OK? Thanks again in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? I can't find the code for `ReadToEndObservable` as an example.

Comment: @Enigmativity I've added all the code to run the `Download` method. For convenience, I've also added it as a GitHub repo: https://github.com/SuperJMN/HttpDownloader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially thought your `ReadToEndObservable` must have had a bug, so I wrote this instead:

```
public static IObservable<byte[]> ReadToEndObservable(this Stream stream, int bufferSize)
    =>
        Observable.Defer<byte[]>(() =>
        {
            var bytesRead = -1;
            var bytes = new byte[bufferSize];
            return
                Observable.While<byte[]>(
                    () => bytesRead != 0,
                    Observable
                        .FromAsync(() => stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bufferSize))
                        .Do(x =>
                        {
                            bytesRead = x;
                        })
                        .Select(x => bytes.Take(x).ToArray()));
        });
```

It still didn't seem to work.

I then tried it with this simple code:

```
IObservable<byte[]> test1 =
    Observable
        .Using(
            () => File.Open(@"{path}\HttpDownloader-master\HttpDownloader-master\HttpDownloader.sln", FileMode.Open),
            s => s.ReadToEndObservable(24));
```

And that worked with my code. And I tried it with yours. It worked.

I thought that there might be something wrong with the stream you're trying to download. There wasn't a problem as such - just that the file is 555MB in size.

I think your code is fine, but the size was simply too big and it was timing out.

Comment: So, do you think my code is OK? No race conditions at all?

Comment: @SuperJMN - It seemed to work fine on the streams that I tried. I just didn't like your code. I think my method is more idiomatic.

Comment: I like your code way more than mine! completely idiomatic. I mistakenly read you answer before. Sorry! I now understand it perfectly. I'm going to do some testing with it and if it works OK (I'm 100% sure it will) I'll stick to your solution. I love how succinct it is!